# QML: acceptedButtons for Flickable

Tags: qt, event-handling, qml, mouseevent

I have a Flickable with some content that has its own `DragHandler`.
I want all drags with the left mouse button to be handled by the content's drag handler, and drags with the right mouse button should be handled by the Flickable. Is that possible?

Example code:

```
Flickable {
    id: canvas

    anchors.fill: parent
    contentWidth: 2*parent.width
    contentHeight: 2*parent.height
    // Something like this
    //acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        width: canvas.width
        height: canvas.height

        DragHandler {
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
            target: null
            onActiveChanged: console.log(`content drag active: ${active}`)
            // Some code to do something with the drag...
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 50
            height: 50
        }
    }
}
```

Goal: I want to move the blue `Rectangle` inside the `Flickable` by dragging with the right mouse button, while drag events with the left mouse button are handled by the `DragHandler` of the blue `Rectangle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [QQuickFlickable source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/quick/items/qquickflickable.cpp.html), I found out that the accepted buttons are statically set to the left button:

> 272: q->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);

So I tried to work around it by introducing another `DragHandler`, which worked for me:

```
Flickable {
    id: canvas

    anchors.fill: parent
    contentWidth: 2*parent.width
    contentHeight: 2*parent.height

    DragHandler {
        property real _startX
        property real _startY

        acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
        dragThreshold: 0
        target: null

        onActiveChanged: {
            if (active) {
                _startX = canvas.contentX
                _startY = canvas.contentY
            }
        }
        onTranslationChanged: {
            canvas.contentX = _startX - translation.x
            canvas.contentY = _startY - translation.y
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        color: "blue"
        width: canvas.width
        height: canvas.height

        DragHandler {
            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
            target: null
            onActiveChanged: console.log(`content drag active: ${active}`)
            // Some code to do something with the drag...
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: 50
            height: 50
        }
    }
}
```

It simply imitates the standard behaviour, but allows to use the `acceptedButtons` property of the `DragHandler` to control the `Flickable` with the button I want.
So far I did not notice any other behaviour of `Flickable` breaking through this workaround.