# Custom DragHandler in Flickable Removes Desired Default Behavior

Tags: c++, qml, drag, flickable

I have a Qt QML 6.5 flickable that I would like to drag the contents of using the right mouse button. Following this question, I implemented a custom DragHandler [QML: acceptedButtons for Flickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65772536/qml-acceptedbuttons-for-flickable) with example code shown below. When I use the default handler, it uses less mouse button to drag but is free flowing so when you flick the contents, it keeps scrolling, and when I drag past the start or end of content it "bounces back". With a custom DragHandler, all that extra behavior goes away. Is there a way to use Right Mouse button AND keep this cool responsive/interactive behavior?

```
  Flickable
        {
            id: mainFlick
            anchors.fill: parent

            contentWidth: mainTimeBarsContent.width; contentHeight: height
            onContentXChanged: { if(flicking) hbar.setPosition(contentX/contentWidth)}
            clip:true
            interactive:false

            DragHandler {
                 property real _startX
                 property real _startY

                 acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
                 dragThreshold: 0
                 target: null
                 yAxis.enabled : false

                 onActiveChanged: {
                     if (active) {
                         _startX = mainFlick.contentX
                         //_startY = mainFlick.contentY
                     }
                 }
                 onTranslationChanged: {
                     mainFlick.contentX = _startX - translation.x
                     //mainFlick.contentY = _startY - translation.y
                 }
             }

    Rectangle { id:contentStuff
      width:5000
      color:"red"
    }
}
```